# (Proof by induction) Finding a closed form solution for a recurrence relation

Tags: proof-writing, induction, recurrence-relations

**Question:** Consider  the following non linear recurrence relation defined for $n \in \mathbb{N}$:

$$a_1=1, \ \ \ a_{n}=na_0+(n-1)a_1+(n-2)a_2+\cdots+2a_{n-2}+a_{n-1}$$

a) Calculate $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4.$

b) Use induction to prove for all positive integers that:

$$a_n=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left[\left(\dfrac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n-\left(\dfrac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n\right]$$
Hi all! I'm having trouble solving this problem. I have no problem with part (a), but I'm having lots of troubles with part (b). I proved the base case (which is quite trivial), but I'm having trouble for the inductive step (proving k->k+1).

[Attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgGfv.png)

I don't know what to do from this point. Thank you!

Comment: Just editted. sorry I uploaded a wrong file

Comment: From the "Attempt" it seems clear that you are given a solution but that you don't understand some part of it. If you tell us which part you don't understand, we might be able to explain it.

Comment: Hi! I'm not given a solution yet. "Attempt" shows my attempt so far at proving the question on word document. Using the induction hypothesis, I was able to derive the last equation I show on "Attempt", but I do not know how that last equation will lead to "k+1" (which is, the closed form solution with n=k+1).

Comment: I don't agree to downgrade this question which evidently shows, attested by the dialog with the OP, that there is real personal  work on a rather special question.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, your recurrence relationship can be transformed into this second order relationship:

> $$\tag{*}a_{n+2}=3a_{n+1}-a_n$$

whose characteristic equation is $r^2-3r+1=0$ with roots $r_1=\tfrac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $r_2=\tfrac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}$, which does not come as a surprise.

Proof of (*). Let us write the definition for two consecutive elements:

$$\tag{1}\begin{cases}a_n=na_0+(n-1)a_1+\cdots+3a_{n-3}+2a_{n-2}+1a_{n-1}\\
a_{n+1}=(n+1)a_0+(n)a_1+\cdots+3a_{n-2}+2a_{n-1}+1a_n
\end{cases}$$

Subtracting the first equation to the second equation, we get:

$$\tag{2}a_{n+1}-a_n=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k$$

If we write (2) at the next order:

$$\tag{3}a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} a_k$$

Subtracting (2) from (3), we get:

$$a_{n+2}-2a_{n+1}+a_n=a_{n+1}$$

which proves relationship (*).

Now, it shouldn't be difficult for you to prove by recurrence that the solution of (*) is  $a_n=\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(r_1^n-r_2^n)$.

Comment: Why didn't you give any comment to my solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Your recurrence is linear. It is just a full history recurrence.

Use generating functions. Define $A(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n z^n$, shift by one and  write:

$\begin{align*}
  a_{n + 1}
    &= \sum_{0 \le k \le n} (n + 1 - k) a_k \\
 \sum_{n \ge 1} a_{n + 1} z^n
    &= \sum_{n \ge 0} z^n \sum_{0 \le k \le n} (n + 1 - k) a_k \\
 \frac{A(z) - a_0}{z}
    &= \left( \sum_{k \ge 0} a_k z^k \right)
         \cdot \left( \sum_{k \ge 0} (k + 1) z^k \right) \\
    &= A(z) \cdot \frac{1}{(1 - z)^2}
\end{align*}$

Solve for $A(z)$, write as partial fractions:

$\begin{align*}
  A(z)
    &= 1 + \frac{z}{1 - 3 z + z^2}
\end{align*}$

Sadly, the roots of the denominator are quite ugly. Say it is:

$\begin{align*}
  A(z)
    &= 1 + \frac{C}{1 - \alpha z} + \frac{D}{1 - \beta z}
\end{align*}$

then your terms are:

$\begin{align*}
  a_n
    &= [z^n] A(z) \\
    &= [n = 1] + C \cdot \alpha^n + D \cdot \beta^n
\end{align*}$

The $[n = 0]$ is Iverson's convention: 1 is the condition is true, 0 otherwise.